# Solving system of differential equations : Wolfram Alpha vs theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

I am burning my brain finding the most correct way to solve a system of differential equations. Here is an example :

$$\begin{cases}
x'=5x-2y\\
y'=-x+6y
\end{cases}
$$

Let's $Y(t)=\begin{pmatrix} x(t) \\ y(t) \end{pmatrix}$.
I use a matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 5 & -2 \\ -1 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$, calculate its eigen values $\lambda_1=7,\lambda_2=4 $ and eigen vectors $ v_1=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, v_2=\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Now 2 options:

- I can use a theorem and find the solution is $Y(t)=c_1 e^{\lambda_1t} u_1 + c_2 e^{\lambda_2t} u_2$
- I can continue using linear algebra, calculate $P$, $D$ and $P^{-1}$ such that $A=P D P^{-1}$ where D is a diagonal matrix.
  $Y'=AY$ so $Y=Ce^{tA}=C P \begin{pmatrix} e^{7t} & 0\\ 0&e^{4t} \end{pmatrix} P^{-1}$

I don't find same results but both are OK (the second is used by Wolfram). Did I misunderstand something? Which one is the best option?

Thanks for you answer

Comment: Looks the same to me?

Comment: But the results are not the same because I multiply by P and $P^{-1}$?

Comment: $C$ is a column vector, as is the solution. It can not stand in first place in a product with matrices.

Comment: Yes you are right, I misplaced C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to write that last formula correctly as
$$
Y(t)=e^{tA}C= P \begin{pmatrix} e^{7t} & 0\\ 0&e^{4t} \end{pmatrix} P^{-1}C,~~~C=Y(0),
$$
then you get the correspondence with the first formula with
$$
P^{-1}C=\pmatrix{c_1\\c_2},
$$
and the columns of $P$ being the eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I think I was disturbed by $P^{-1}$